# how to convert terminal shell commands to .command file

Tags: bash, macos, shell

How do I convert the following terminal commands to a `.command` file so I can directly double click to run the command

1. `cd /Applications/some\ apps\ to\ run/foo.app/Contents/MacOS`
2. `./fooexecutable -arg 12345`

Comment: This is not really a programming question, and I suggest that you ask this at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: isn't bash/sh a programming language?

Comment: Yes, but you don't write a program to reach your goal; you already **do have** a script (series of commands) and want to use your Desktop (GUI) for executing them. This question is related to configuring the GUI, and as such dependent on the Desktop Manager in use. Since you use macos, this means that the question is about how to use your Mac so that you can start a program by double clicking on an icon. _AskDifferent_ is the stackexchange site devoted to **all** Apple stuff (programming **and** using).

Comment: if your answer is a yes, i believe it's the appropriate place to ask such questions

Comment: In this case, I don't know what the bash program you are going to write is supposed to do. I understood your question in the way that you want to put a few bash commands into a script and want to **double-click** somewhere (an icon on your desktop?) to run those commands. Neither of these two problems is related to programming. But maybe I'm missing something; in this case, perhaps you could clarify your question, so we know at which bash-related programming problem you are stuck.

Comment: you're just being picky, look at how @SparkDev is answering questions because he understood the questions unlike you who just want to argue here. Look at your profile, you've replied on many bash/sh questions but today you feel like closing this questions huh? having a bad day bro?

Comment: It's not about the content of your question, but the suitable site for asking it. BTW, I was not aware that you can double script a file name in Finder and it would execute the script, and I still wonder where then the stdout and stderr goes to. That's for me the interesting part of the accepted answer (and the main reason why I would have asked this at AskDifferent). The rest of that answer is trivial, and the answer as a whole does not reveal any notable programming topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just open what ever Texteditor you use and make a new file called `example.command` (make sure you turn file extensions on so you don't create `example.command.txt`) type line by line all the commands in that you want to run like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /Applications/some\ apps\ to\ run/foo.app/Contents/MacOS
./fooexecutable -arg 12345
```

now  execute `chmod a+x ./example.command`

and now you can run it either in the shell with `./example.command`
or as you requested with double click via finder.

Comment: not working, executable arguments is ignored "-arg 12345"

Comment: fooexecutable program takes an argument "-arg" and it's value is "12345"

Comment: why do you write -arg before 12345?

Comment: It's just the way this fooexecutable program accepts arguments

Comment: maybe your code doesn't work

Comment: every program get arguments like this

Comment: you're correct, the arguments are accepted like the way you answered, it's a typo in my arguments which caused the program error. I've marked you answer accepted, thanks for your help!